# Installing scikit-learn in docker with python 3.8

Tags: python, docker, scikit-learn, python-3.8

I have the following dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

RUN pip install scikit-learn==0.21.3
```

The `docker build .` doesn't work, returning

```
        from Cython import Tempita
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cython'
    ----------------------------------------
```

Is there a way to use scikit-learn in python 3.8 via docker? I am particularly interested to build on top of `python:3.8-slim-buster`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to add this to your docker file to add Cython layer before you try to install scikit-learn

```
RUN pip install Cython --install-option="--no-cython-compile"
```